# Swift : how to work with 2D array and Calculate on them

Tags: swift

Hi I have problem with swift 2D array and calculate on them like : multiple , sum , subtract ... but I get error like : cannot convert value type

this is my code:

```
let ar1: [[Int]] = [[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]

let ar2: [[Int]] = [[2,4], [6,8],[10,12],[14,16]]

var ar3: [[Int]] = []

for i in 0...ar1.count-1 
       {

for j in 0...ar1.count-1 
{

ar3.append(ar1[i][j] + ar2 [i][j])

         }
}
```

I have to do it by for loop please help me

Comment: Can you add your desired output for ar3?

Comment: Is your goal to end up adding 1+2, 2+4, 3+6, 4+8, etc.? If so you mighty want to look up `flatmap()`, you would only need one loop then.

Comment: i have to use for loop because of my teacher no fucntion

Comment: what is flatmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ar3` contains elements of type `[Int]`, so consequently `ar3.append(…)` needs an object of type `[Int]`. But you're not giving it an `[Int]`, you're giving it an `Int` (i.e. the result of the expression `ar1[i][j] + ar2[i][j]`).

If you want to sum `ar1` and `ar2` into `[1+2, 2+4, 3+6, …]`:

```
var ar3 = [Int]()

for i in ar1 {
    for j in ar2 {
        ar3.append(i + j)
    }
}
```

(or a functional way to do the same: `zip(ar1, ar2).flatMap { zip($0, $1).map(+) }`)

If you want to sum `ar1` and `ar2` into `[[1+2, 2+4], [3+6, 4+8], …]`:

```
var ar3 = [[Int]]()

for i in ar1 {
    ar3.append([])
    for j in ar2 {
        ar3.last!.append(i + j)
    }
}
```

(or a functional way to do the same: `zip(ar1, ar2).map { zip($0, $1).map(+) }`)

Comment: @MahdiMahjoobe How about now?

Comment: you mean i have to change ar3.append (ar1 [i][j] + ar2 [i][j]) or change declare of ar3

Comment: Yes, one of those. Either you give an `[Int]` to `ar3.append`, or append to something that takes an `Int`.

Comment: It is a week or two Im working on programming so I cant understand fully what are you saying

Comment: ar1 , ar2 are 2D array i will put them in simple array (ar3) is it possible

Comment: `[Int]` means "an array of `Int`s". `Int` is a single integer. `[[Int]]` is an array that _contains_ arrays of `Int`s. So it is really about what you want `ar3` to be. If you want it to be an array of integers then you need to change the declaration, if you want it to be a 2D array then you need to change what you are appending to it.

Comment: How can i learn this way you understand code very well and answer it is there any special book ?? or site please help i am starting

Comment: I think the Swift Programming Language book is pretty good, it's free on iBooks.